# Will std::swap still be defined by including algorithm in C++0x?

Tags: c++, c++11, header-files, swap, std

The `swap` function template was moved from `<algorithm>` to `<utility>` in C++0x. Does the former include the latter in C++0x? Or do they both include a common header the defines `swap`?

In other words, is the following code guaranteed to compile in C++0x?

```
#include <algorithm>   // will this pull in std::swap?

// ...

using std::swap;
swap(a, b);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The FDIS (n3290), in Annex C, "Compatibility", C.2.7 says:

> 17.6.3.2
>
> Eﬀect on original feature: Function swap moved to a diﬀerent
>   header
>
> Rationale: Remove dependency on <algorithm> for swap.
>
> Eﬀect on
>   original feature: Valid C++ 2003 code that has been compiled expecting
>   swap to be in <algorithm> may have to instead include <utility>.

So no, it's not guaranteed to compile, this is intentionally a breaking change. Whether individual implementations will actually break C++03 code is another matter. As you point out it's easy enough for them not to, by defining `swap` via either header. But there's a choice between making it easier to port C++03 code to C++0x, vs. helping people write strictly conforming C++0x.

Comment: Why hasn't `std::swap` always resided inside `<utility>`? :)

Comment: The committee was asleep at the wheel on this one.  Many of the algorithms in `<algorithm>` use `swap`, and so it must be in scope.  We should've guaranteed that `<algorithm>` still pulls in `swap`, because in practice it *always* will.  E.g. `int i, j; std::iter_swap(&i, &j);` *has* to work!

Comment: @Howard: and is it right that once user-defined types are brought into play, it *must* be the "real" `std::swap` used by those algorithms, not just some other code that has the effect of swapping the values, because the user might specialize `std::swap` and the algorithms then must use the specialization?

Comment: @Steve: Yes, `std::swap` must be in scope.  However it is not a good idea at all to put your `swap` overload in namespace std.  Put it in the same namespace as the object you are swapping.  `swap` is part of **your** object's interface, no different than its assignment operator.

Comment: @Howard: sure, all I meant by it is that because the implementation has to be able to call `std::swap` specializations, it would be a very peculiar implementation indeed that would be capable of doing that without incidentally making `std::swap` available for the rest of the TU.